# How to place different content (shortcuts) on windows 10 virtual desktops?

Tags: windows-10, virtual-desktop

Is it possible to have different programs set on virtual desktops? <s>just like as  it when extending desktop area on second monitor or</s>  as ubuntu virtual desktop behavior ?

Comment: "extending desktop area on second monitor" is different from "virtual desktop". If you have a multi-monitor setup then each screen already has a different desktop. If you have different shortcuts positions on virtual desktops then when you delete that virtual desktop, the configuration is lost

Comment: I changed question about virtual desktops. hope be clear now.